# How to read a property from the FARM property bag using jquery or SPServices

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, spservices

The question its very clear, I lknow how to read a property from the property bag in c#

But now I need to know how to do it in jquery or with SPServices. Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
var webProperties;

function getWebProperties() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    webProperties = clientContext.get_web().get_allProperties();
    clientContext.load(webProperties);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function.createDelegate(this, this.getPropertyBagSuccess), function.createDelegate(this, this.getPropertyBagFail));
}

function getPropertyBagSuccess() {
    var propertyBag = webProperties.get_fieldValues();
    if(propertyBag.YourProperty != undefined)
    {
        alert(propertyBag.YourProperty);
    }
    else
    {
        alert("property not found!");
    }
}

function getPropertyBagFail(args, sender)
{
    alert("error trying to read propertybag");
}
```

Comment: I need it from the FARM object, not the current site or current web, thats the trick

Comment: What do you mean with farm object, all properties are distributed on farm servers. By farm object you mean root site?